# Elastic search 5.0 and getting ordered partitions

Tags: elasticsearch-5

I'm using the elastic search 5 version and I want to use scroll elastic search aggregation like here ([link](https://lukasmestan.com/learn-how-to-use-scroll-elasticsearch-aggregation/)). I have a query:

```
GET data/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "values"" {
      "terms": {
        "field": "currency",
        "include": {
          "partition": 0,
          "num_partitions": 3
        }
        "size": "5",
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...and i get the first 5 elements ordered for A to Z. When I fetch next query with `partition = 1` I get another chunk of elements but its also ordered separatedly from A to Z! So, it's there a way to get elements in proper order or from already ordered list/bucket?